# $1$ as difference of composites with same number of prime factors

Tags: nt.number-theory

I noticed and found only first three cases:

We can write $1$ as difference of two composites that have one prime factor $$3^2-2^3=1$$

and as difference of two composites that have two prime factors $$3\cdot 5 - 7\cdot 2 = 1$$

and as difference of two composites that have three prime factors $$2^2 \cdot 3^2 \cdot 43-7 \cdot 13 \cdot 17=1$$

I believe that this holds for every $k \in \mathbb N$, that is, that for every $k \in \mathbb N$ there exist composites $a_k$ and $b_k$ that have exactly $k$ prime factors and are such that we have $a_k-b_k=1$.

> Is my belief true? Is this known? What is known about all of this and similar problems? Can someone find solutions for some larger $k$´s?

Examples exist at least for $k=1,2,...11$ by [this list](http://oeis.org/A093548) .

Comment: Also asked on MSE: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2700917/1-as-difference-of-composites-with-same-number-of-prime-factors

Comment: Why close? This seems to be pretty research level.

Comment: The smallest example for $k=3$ is $3\cdot7\cdot11-2\cdot5\cdot23=231-230=1$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson And the smallest examples, so far, for $k=1,2,3$, all three have $3$ as a factor of a bigger number, and $2$ as a factor of a smaller number.

Comment: The smallest example for $k=4$ is $7315-7314=1$ (and 3 is not a factor of 7315).

Comment: @GerryMyerson But it is of 7314, so of a two numbers in our smallest examples at least one has 3 as a factor, so far.

Comment: It is not surprising, is it, that the smallest example involves the smallest primes?

Comment: @GerryMyerson I am aware that they almost always should tend to involve as small as possible number of smallest primes, it is a question how long will 3 be a factor of at least one of  a numbers that are smallest examples, I do not know how long.

Answer (score 12):

Erdos mentions in his book "*Topics in the Theory of Numbers*" the following:

> "It is stil unkown if the equation $\omega(n+1)=\omega(n)$ has
>   infinitely many solutions...It is known that $|\omega(n+1)-\omega(n)|$
>   takes a certain value infinitely often".

Here $\omega(x)$ denotes the number of prime factors of $x$.

So, I suppose this is still open. I am not sure if there is an update on this problem.

Comment: Do you know is $\omega(n)=\omega(n+k)$ open for every $k \in \mathbb N$, in the sense of infinity of solutions?

Comment: @Shalom Unfortunately no.

Comment: Actually, it is by now known. see: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1105.1621v1.pdf